# gravity forms fire js event on successfull form submission

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is it in gravity forms anyhow possible to fire an javascript event on an successful ajax form transmittion?

Adding html javascript into the displayed response does not seem to work eg:

```
<script>console.log("successful-form-transmition");</script>
```

Comment: Adding plain javascript to text also works. Had an typo in "scirpt" which prevented it from working.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's an event fired upon successful Gravity Forms submission: `gform_confirmation_loaded`. You can use it with jQuery like so:

```
$(document).on("gform_confirmation_loaded", function (e, form_id) {
  // code to run upon successful form submission
});
```

[See documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_loaded/)

Comment: Thanks for this - I could only get it working with bind though, in case anyone else can't get it going -> `jQuery(document).bind("gform_confirmation_loaded", function (e, form_id) {`

Comment: thanks, but can I put this code in an html field in the form? dont seem to be working for me

Comment: And while probably obvious, make sure you embedded the form with ajax activated on.