# How can I bind js event on Gravity Froms submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to bind js event on Gravity Forms submission. I've enabled ajax for that form, I tried solutions described on official Gravity Forms [support forum](https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/topic/onclick-tracking) and example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565566/gravity-forms-fire-js-event-on-successfull-form-submission) but they didn't work for me, also I've read documentation on GF official site, but it didn't clear the situation for me. I wonder where problem is, my site is on WordPress v.4.7.11 with jQuery v.1.12.4. Here is code I've placed as html element in my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).bind('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, 
      form_id){
           if(form_id == 132){
               console.log("success");
           }
    });
 });
</script>
```

P.S. Here is the code that works, but it works after form is rendered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(){
   console.log("success");
 });
</script>
```

Any help and tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try changing to `.on` instead of `.bind`

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried it already, didn't help.